# Spacing/Width for CSS

Tags: html, css, formatting, styling, spacing

Hello I am new to CSS and trying to create a 3 column basic web page. My HTML is as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="{{ config('app.locale') }}">
  <title>Test Title</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/all.css" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>

<!--Top masthead of the website-->
<header id="welcome-masthead">
  <h1> Sexy Website Header </h1>
</header>

<!--Left portion of the website m-->
<article id="welcome-left-section">
  <nav>
    <a href="#welcome-masthead">- To Top</a> <br>
    <br>
    <a href="#welcome-bottom">- To Bottom</a> <br>
  </nav>
</article>

<!--Center portion of the website -->
<article id="welcome-center-section">
  <div>
    <p> Some text in the center section </p>
  </div>
</article>

<!--Right portion of the website-->
<article id="welcome-right-section">
  <div>
    <p> Some text in the right section </p>
  </div>
</article>

<footer id="welcome-bottom">
  <div>
    <p> This is the footer </p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

I have created a css file and have been playing around with margins and width settings and for the most part I have fully created everything to be functional and evenly spaced for all screen resolutions (that is zooming in and out does not drastically change the look of the page). However, there is one part (the gap between the center section and right section) that grows increasingly larger the more the page is zoomed out. I am unable to find a solution that kind of "sticks" the two sections together keeping an even 2em distance between the two.

My css is as follows.

```
#welcome-masthead {
    height: 6em;

    margin: 2em 5em;
    padding-top: 0.1px;

    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center;

    background-color: #e8eaed;
}

#welcome-left-section {
    float: left;

    padding: 0.8em;
    margin-right: 2em;
    margin-left: 2em;

    height: 1000px;
    width: 10%;

    background-color: #e8eaed;
    border: thin,solid,#000000;
}

#welcome-center-section {
    padding: 0.8em;
    margin-right: 2em;

    height: 1000px;
    width: 61%;

    display: inline-block;

    background-color: #e8eaed;
    border: thin,solid,#000000;
}

#welcome-right-section {
    float: right;

    padding: 0.8em;
    margin-right:2em;

    height: 1000px;
    width: 20%;

    background-color: #e8eaed;
    border:thin,solid,#000000;
}   

#welcome-bottom {
    width:auto;
    height: 5em;

    padding: 0.8em;
    margin: 2em;

    background-color: #e8eaed;
    border:thin,solid,#000000;
}
```

Any help is appreciated! I am rather new to css so I apologise if this is a silly mistake!

Comment: Normally you should use `class` instead of `id` for CSS styling. Also, there are multiple errors in your CSS. Last, you can make a JSFiddle so that we can reference your case easier.

Answer (score 0):

use this css-code:

```
welcome-center-section,
welcome-right-section,
welcome-left-section {
    float: left;
    width: 33.3%;
    }
.clearfix {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    }
```

***NOTE: add clearfix-class beneath the closing tag of the right side column***

```
<article id="welcome-right-section">
  <div>
    <p> Some text in the right section </p>
  </div>
</article>
<div class=clearfix></div> <!-- To reset float -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't really getting full control of your horizontal dimensions since after defining the width you added margins of a different measurement. The widths (61%, 20%, and 10%) add up to 91%, but you still don't know what the 2em margins give you, especially since the EM is a character — which changes when you zoom in or out.

My advice is to use flex. Read up on it. It is very simple to use. Here is a straight-forward example of what you are trying to accomplish.

```css
.container {display: flex; justify-content: space-between; width: 100%}
.leftcolumn,.middlecolumn, .rightcolumn {width: 28%}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="leftcolumn">Left leaning material</div>
<div class="middlecolumn">Moderate material</div>
<div class="rightcolumn">Right leaning material</div>
</div>
```

Another thing to keep in mind is that padding actually grows the element outward instead of pushing inward. This further confuses the measurements. With flex you can eliminate margins and padding. If you must have padding on those columns it might be neater (and more cross-browser correct) to simply place another DIV inside the columns with a margin.

If for some reason you don't want to use Flex you can always create spacer DIVs in between the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Great to hear your learning web design! Since you are just starting I thought it was worth mentioning that although using `float` is perfectly valid, the more modern way (and the way that most frameworks are heading (e.g. [Bootstrap 4](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/))) is to use [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Flexbox allows you to achieve the same thing but a lot of the work is done for you, and its much more responsive friendly.

Browser support for flexbox is pretty damn good now as well see [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox/).

I have recreated what you have done using flexbox to give you an idea.

As I say, this is the way of the future so might as well learn it.

PS. Make sure you view in full screen so you can resize and see the flexbox magic.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper > * {
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 1 100%;
}

.header {
  height: 6em;
  background: #e8eaed;
}

.footer {
  background: lightgreen;
}

.main {
  text-align: left;
  background: deepskyblue;
  height: 500px;
}

.aside-1 {
  background: gold;
}

.aside-2 {
  background: hotpink;
}

@media all and (min-width: 600px) {
  .aside {
    flex: 1 auto;
  }
}
@media all and (min-width: 800px) {
  .main {
    flex: 3 0px;
  }

  .aside-1 {
    order: 1;
  }

  .main {
    order: 2;
  }

  .aside-2 {
    order: 3;
  }

  .footer {
    order: 4;
  }
}
body {
  padding: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header class="header"><h1> Sexy Website Header </h1></header>
  <article class="main">
    <p>Some text in the center section</p>  
  </article>
  <aside class="aside aside-1">Aside 1</aside>
  <aside class="aside aside-2">Aside 2</aside>
  <footer class="footer">Footer</footer>
</div>
```

Here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p80bvj4d/) in case you need it.